# How to Implement Separate Projects for ASP.NET MVC 4 and ASP.NET Web API

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a large ASP.NET MVC/Web API project and wanted to separate out the controllers into their own project (as described in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj190803.aspx).  The difference is that I'm needing to separate out the ASP.NET Web API controllers, not “normal” MVC controllers.

In my solution, I have two separate projects:

- One ASP.NET MVC 4 project for serving up HTML/CSS/JavaScript (note
  I'm not using any standard MVC controllers, this project is all
  client/browser-side code that makes jQuery/Ajax calls to the Web API)
- One ASP.NET Web API project (this project is only the
  ApiController(s), no views, HTML, etc., I'm still wanting the Web API
  project to be hosted in IIS, not self-hosted)

Anyway, I’ve seen other posts and such that haven’t really explained my exact situation, and I'm having trouble getting this solution working.

How can I break out my Web API controllers into their own separate project and use them from my HTML/JavaScript code in my separate MVC project?  And, how do I call the API’s endpoints from my JavaScript/jQuery code in the separate MVC project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Web Api and MVC are in different projects and probably they will run in different domains making the communication little difficult from client-side beause of cross-domain issue.

Though you can try JSONP or CORS but they are not going to be much useful (one is a hack and the other is not widely supported in browsers) and so you have to create wrapper MVC controllers in your MVC project that will talk to the Web Api through `HttpClient` class.

Your javascript will make calls to your MVC controllers and this way you can avoid the cross domain issues.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  It makes sense what you're saying.  The cross domain issue is probably why I couldn't get it to work in my prototype - that is, my MVC project is using http://localhost:50285/ and my Web API project is using http://localhost:50283/, and using jQuery.ajax with a URL of http://localhost:50283/api/Values, I can't the JSON values from the Web API project into the MVC project (it's giving me the error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50283/api/Values. Origin http://localhost:50285 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.).  Maybe I'll ditch the idea of separating the

Comment: MVC and Web API projects as I'm not sure how to write a wrapper around an MVC controller and then call the Web API project from it.

Comment: Check this post http://johnnycode.com/2012/02/23/consuming-your-own-asp-net-web-api-rest-service/. If the Web API is only consumed from the MVC project and not from anywhere you can include them in the MVC project itself by this way you can avoid cross-domain issues.

Comment: Thanks again Mark.  I've had to switch my attention and energies to another project, so I was unable to implement your suggestion (including the link you provided).  It appears that your suggestion would solve my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @Imttag I've created a small post on this subject right here http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/10/asp_net_mvc_vs_webapi. You may like it.

Comment: What about this? http://www.xyz.com and http://api.xyz.com. Do these URLs belong to the same domain? In that case, would it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your API controllers into another project, that's fine. Just assure that you have all required assemblies referenced. I suggest take a look at Nuget packages to assure you have them all.
For api and web separation, use proper routing that's all I guess. Check "WebApiConfig.cs" in App_Start folder at your MVC project. API routing has basically "API/..." at the beginning, so it wont make a mess with your mvc site.
So at the end you will get something like this:

```
 http://localhost/products
 http://localhost/api/products
```

First process request at mvc site, second at WebApi.

Comment: Thanks for the info Jaroslav.  As my comment to Mark indicates, I'm not sure how to make it work (and I don't know if I have enough time to figure it out and implement it).